# I think I'm making an error in my implementation of least squares but I'm not sure (python).

Tags: optimization, least-squares

Starting to read a book and the author goes into least squares etc. and shows this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB0jz.jpg).

Thought I'd do it myself. Using the lin alg formula, there I noticed I was getting slightly different results, and after experimenting around a little I found depending on the constraints/parameters I chose they sometimes were completely wrong.

Could it be the formula $param = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ only really works on paper, or better said not in a digital domain where I am using a finite set of samples? And one - on the PC - has to revert back to taking the derivative of the error function and then using something like newton's method to find the optimal parameters?

I could post my code (python), but I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right, it's just the functions I get are weird and the only explanation I can see is that it's an analog<->digital thing.

```
x_axis = np.linspace(-10,10,50)
#x_axis=np.linspace(-50,50,1000)

def create_data(num_param):
   v_x=x_axis
   y=np.sin(v_x) 
   err=np.array([(int(10*random())-5)/15 for i in range(len(y))])
   y+=err
   A=[]
   for x in v_x:
       A.append([x**i for i in range(num_param)])

   A=np.matrix(A)

   return A,y

def poly_func(x,param):
    return sum(param[i]*(x**i) for i in range(0,len(param)))

def main():

    A,y=create_data(10)
    plot_old_y=y
    param=(A.T*A).I*A.T*np.matrix(y).T

    param=np.ravel(np.array(param))
    print(param)

    v_x=np.ravel(np.array(A[:,1]))
    new_y=poly_func(v_x,param)

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(x_axis,np.sin(x_axis),color='r')
    plt.plot(v_x,new_y ,color='b')
    plt.scatter(v_x,plot_old_y)
    plt.show()

main()
```

[Two example images,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIvUp.jpg) note if I zoomed out in the 'good' fit it would turn into what looks like a logistic function.

The first thing that tipped me off was that unlike his picture I was getting completely different fits at the orders he had, that let to me experimenting more.

Comment: the picture you posted shows polynomial regression, while the formula you posted looks like linear regression.    Perhaps you are expecting something different?  it's certainly not an analog<->digital thing, the computer can cope just fine.  But you haven't explained enough about your code or your weirdness for me to figure out what is up.

Comment: okay im clearly doing something wrong then, i thought the lin alg $was$ with polynomials, that's how one sets the $A$ matrix up (?), im gonna add my code

Comment: Actually I need to correct my comment - you are correct, that formula is for both multivariable linear regression and single-var polynomial regression.  The latter bit about weirdness and code not being defined well enough still stands.

Comment: ye i was wondering, added code

Comment: In your second example you are trying to make a degree $50$ polynomial fit to $\sin(x)$ on $[-50,50]$. This is a bad idea and it's not strange that it does not match well. Note that the plot from the book make the fit over one period of $\sin(x)$, i.e. $[0,\pi]$, you are trying to make the fit over $16$ periods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is correct.  Indeed, even in your pictures show that it is regressing on sin.  Some things I noticed, however:

- as one commentor already pointed out, the windows your using are just too wide for you to see the results you are looking for.  Try keeping things to a np.linspace(0,1,100), and adjust your sin function so you have $\text{sin}(2\pi*x)$, that way your sin function gets though a whole period in $[0,1]$.
- You have different data that you are regression on than the book does.  In fact, your data comes from sin +/- your error formula, and you have one such data point for every single point in your space.  Don't get me wrong here, there is no such thing as too much data, but since the space is saturated with your generated points, and since your error formula isn't actually gaussian noise, you're getting actually learning the shape of sin + your psuedo-random generator instead of sin.  Try to have fewer points to learn from, say, just 10.

Comment: Man I just spent 20 minutes uploading new images when I suddenly realized the only reason my pictures look different than his is because when testing my function I'm using the same number of points as I had data points, whereas he ups resolution by quite a bit. This led to my version not having a visible overfitting effect that should be happening. Stupid. Thanks anyways.